How to use HTTP Policy Transform Extension to set additional Query Params?
[Background]
I would like to append additional Query Params to all incoming requests going into my Mulesoft REST-API app. The idea is to develop a Mulesoft Custom Policy, with HTTP Policy Transform Extension to achieve it.
[Problem statement]
Let's say the incoming requests url is //localhost:8081/hellomule?id=1, how do I use HTTP Policy Transform Extension to append additional query params. For example, let's append a query param of ?name=jackson.

Original URL: //localhost:8081/hellomule?id=1

Expected: //localhost:8081/hellomule?id=1&name=jackson

As observed above, the expectation is that query params name=jackson will be appended onto the original url


[template.xml]
In this file, I have written an implementation to hardcode name:jackson as query params.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="....."
      xmlns:xsi="....."
      xmlns:http-policy="....."
      xmlns:http-transform="....."
      xsi:schemaLocation=".....">
  
    <http-policy:proxy name="{{{policyId}}}-custom-policy">
        <http-policy:source>

            <!-- This is not working -->
            <http-transform:set-requester-request>
                <http-transform:query-params>#[{('name': 'jackson')}]</http-transform:query-params>
            </http-transform:set-requester-request>
 
            <http-policy:execute-next />
 
        </http-policy:source>
    </http-policy:proxy>
</mule>

I have used <http-transform:set-requester-request> and <http-transform:query-params> to inject the query params of {('name': 'jackson')}, however it does not seems to be working. The url remains the same //localhost:8081/hellomule?id=1, without &name=jackson.
I am guessing I am missing things, or I have misunderstood the use of the HTTP Policy Transform Extension. I am hopeful to get some advise from the community please, thank you.

It seems correct. Did you try with a fixed name?
